# How to place a video in html using bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, video, bootstrap-4

I am working on a website in which I want to place a video in html using **boostrap 4**. The video is in mp4 format.

The html code which I have tried/used in order to place a video is:

```
<header class="container border masthead_video text-white text-center">
   <div class=""
      type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there is any predefined header class in bootstrap like we have [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) where we can place images and videos. Also, what changes I need to make in order to place a video here:

```
 <div class=""
          type="video/mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"></video>
 </div>
```

Comment: you probably want to use a `<video>` tag not a `<div>` tag. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: @zgood Can you give me a little bit more pointer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/embed/) detail embedding videos in html while using Bootstrap 4. Try replacing your video snippet with this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

The `embed-responsive-16by9` means it's for 16:9 aspect ratios. There are other options like:

- `embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3` for 4:3 ratios
- `embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1` for 1:1 ratios
- etc

Comment: Yes. You can also move around the `div` if you'd like to rearrange your view.

Comment: Ok..also I am wondering if there is any header class in bootstrap like we have [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) ?

Comment: I am using header class as mentioned in the question, so I am wondering if it exists in bootstrap 4.

Comment: A header for your video? If you want a video equivalent for navbar there currently is no such thing.

Comment: Do we have that in bootstrap 4 ?

Comment: Currently no, you are asking for a video component. What bootstrap does offer is a [card component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/) which can combine nicely. http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/6083/ I've also updated the fiddle to bring in files.

Comment: Perfectly make sense. I am just thinking if we have any **header class in Bootstrap 4** doesn't matter if its a video or an image.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146462/how-to-place-a-dropdown-at-the-top-most-right-section-of-a-video-in-bootstrap-4). I am wondering if you can have a look. Just want to place a dropdown at the top most extreme right of a video.