# How to align footer items in line in css/Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, inline, footer

I am working on the footer section in which I have `Social Media Icons` and `Contact Us` section.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2uqk89cn/1/embedded/result) for it. At this moment in the fiddle, `Contact Us` and `Social Media Icons` are in separate lines not `inline`.

The HTML code which I have used to order to place `Social Media Icons` and `Contact Us` content is:

```html
<div class="fixed-bottom footer_fixed">
  <p class="mx-0 mb-2 mt-2 text-center">
    <i class="fas fa-phone pr-1"></i>
    <a href="tel:+1234567890" class="pr-3">
          +1 234 456 7890
          </a>
    <span class="static-email">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope pl-3 pr-1"></i>
          <a href="mailto:helloworld@world.com">
          helloworld@world.com
          </a>
          </span>
    <ul class="social-network social-circle">
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/" target="_blank" class="icoLinkedin" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>

<br><br>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should do in the CSS in the fiddle so that I am able to align items (`Contact Us` and `Social Media Icons`) in one single line with **Social media Icons coming right to** `Contact Us`.

Comment: use bootstrap grid if you are using bootstrap

Comment: @Rumesh Can you give me a pointer in the fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap grid.
See below example (please check it in full screen view)

```css
 /*---------- Footer -----------*/

/*
.footer
{
    background-color: #343a40;
    background:url("../images/footer_background_full.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.footer_overlay
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #212529;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
*/

.footer {
 color: white;
 padding-top: 44px;
 background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

.footer a {
 color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
}

.footer a:hover {
 color: #fb875c
}

.footer .menu-items a {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.appstore_soon_image_wrapper {
 max-width: 140px;
 max-height: 50px;
}

.appstore_soon_image_wrapper img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 object-fit: contain;
}

.footer_img {
 width: 155px;
 height: 45px;
}

.back_to_top a {
 color: #ff8b5a;
}

.copyrights_wrapper {
 border-top: 1px solid #666;
}

.p_copyright {
 color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul.social-network {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
 display: inline;
 /* margin: 0 3px; */
}

.social-circle li a {
 display: inline-block;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 /*border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; */
 text-align: center;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: inherit;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.social-circle li i {
 margin: 0;
 /*line-height:30px;*/
 line-height: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #C0C0C0;
}

/* color of social icons on hover */

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoTwitter:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i,
.social-network a.icoInstagram:hover i {
 color: #ff8b5a;
}

.social-network a:hover {
 border-color: #ff8b5a;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .appstore_1 {
  display: block;
 }
 .appstore_2 {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .appstore_1 {
  display: none;
 }
 .appstore_2 {
  display: block;
 }
}

/*
.footer_head
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
*/

.footer_fixed {
 background-color: #343a40;
 color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="fixed-bottom footer_fixed">


  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">

    <i class="fas fa-phone pr-1"></i>
    <a href="tel:+1234567890" class="pr-3">
     +1 234 456 7890
    </a>
    <span class="static-email">
     <i class="fas fa-envelope pl-3 pr-1"></i>
     <a href="mailto:letsRuckify@Ruckify.com">
      helloworld@world.com
     </a>
    </span>

   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">

    <ul class="social-network social-circle">
     <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/" target="_blank" class="icoLinkedin" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
  </div>

  </p>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To learn more about bootstrap grid : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bjme2z/8/embedded/result) with all your code. I am wondering what changes I need to do now so that I can center the footer contents. At this moment, its not centered

Comment: I'm bit confused with your requirement. Do you want social media icons on bottom of links??

Comment: otherwise it will does not look good with everything centered

Comment: The contents should be the center of a bar. At this moment, it is slightly up.

Comment: I agree with you but that is the requirement. They want me to bring the contents at the center which is slightly up at this moment.

Comment: I think, I explained my question in a wrong way. I want the contents to be vertically centred not horizontally.  At this moment, it is not vertically centred, it is slightly up.

Comment: The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bjme2z/46/) which you sent me is horizontally centred not vertically. Sorry I didn't explain you in right way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use display flex

```
.fixed-bottom p {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.fixed-bottom .social-network {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can update me in the fiddle. In that way, I will be able to visualize in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one. I think it solves your problem.
[`JSfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ke3r5wyf/)

```css
/*---------- Footer -----------*/


/*
.footer
{
    background-color: #343a40;
    background:url("../images/footer_background_full.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.footer_overlay
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #212529;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
*/

.footer {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 44px;
  background-color: rgb(243, 243, 243);
}

.footer a {
  color: rgb(138, 138, 138);
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: #fb875c
}

.footer .menu-items a {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.appstore_soon_image_wrapper {
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.appstore_soon_image_wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.footer_img {
  width: 155px;
  height: 45px;
}

.back_to_top a {
  color: #ff8b5a;
}

.copyrights_wrapper {
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
}

.p_copyright {
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  /* margin: 0 3px; */
}

.social-circle li a {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; */
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.social-circle li i {
  margin: 0;
  /*line-height:30px;*/
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #C0C0C0;
}


/* color of social icons on hover */

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoTwitter:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i,
.social-network a.icoInstagram:hover i {
  color: #ff8b5a;
}

.social-network a:hover {
  border-color: #ff8b5a;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .appstore_1 {
    display: block;
  }
  .appstore_2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .appstore_1 {
    display: none;
  }
  .appstore_2 {
    display: block;
  }
}


/*
.footer_head
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight:400;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
*/

.footer_fixed {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fixed-bottom footer_fixed d-flex justify-content-center pt-3 pb-3">
    <p class="mx-0 m-0 text-center">
      <i class="fas fa-phone pr-1"></i>
      <a href="tel:+1234567890" class="pr-3">
                +1 234 456 7890
            </a>
      <span class="static-email">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope pl-3 pr-1"></i>
                <a href="mailto:letsRuckify@Ruckify.com">
                    helloworld@world.com
                </a>
            </span>
      <ul class="social-network social-circle m-0 ml-3">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="icoTwitter" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/" target="_blank" class="icoLinkedin" title="LinkedIn"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" class="icoInstagram" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You fiddle looks good but I have decided to use grid-system as suggested by Ramesh. Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bjme2z/8/embedded/result). I am wondering what changes I need to do now so that I can center the footer contents. At this moment, its not centered.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar The answer looks great. I will definitely use it. Also, I have use Bootstrap Grid system in order to solve my question. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19bjme2z/8/embedded/result) with the Bootstrap Grid System. I am wondering if there is any way if I can align the contents at the center. At this moment, contents are not at the center.